# Converting Excel spreadsheet to XML

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet. When I tried to save the Excel spreadsheet as XML, all the leading zeros are lost. I am using Excel 2016. I have 63138 rows in excel spreadsheet. Below is the sample data of my excel spreadsheet.

```
Col1  col2     col3  col4    col5
32    000001    000    001    1
32    000032    000    032    22
32    000111    000    111    032
```

How can I prevent excel to drop off the leading zeros when I save the file as XML. All the last columns have been formatted as text. Below is the image:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would seem that you are relying on custom number formatting to achieve the leading zeroes. You need to change the values to the range.text value and format the column as text.

Comment: All the last columns are formatted as text. I attached the picture too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XlRangeValueDataType` enumeration for the Value property of Range object. All zeros are preserved. For your example with five columns you will get:

```
Sub GGG()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xml$

    xml = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)

    '// Save string here somewhere

End Sub
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"
    ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s63">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Inherit" x:CharSet="204" ss:Color="#303336"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s68">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4" ss:StyleID="s68"
   ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Col1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">col2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">col3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">col4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">col5</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">32</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">32</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000032</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">032</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">22</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">32</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000111</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">111</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">032</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```